# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer not displaying text (wrong cmaps path)

Tags: angular, assets, pdf.js, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I am using the latest stable version of **ngx-extended-pdf-viewer** (4.1.2) and Angular 9.1. Everything work's great but after the application is built certain PDF-files don't show any text. It turns out that the reason was that the request for the .bcmap files fails.

Instead of requesting the **bcmap** files from:
*my-application/**en**/assets/cmaps/Adobe-CNS1-UCS2.bcmap*

... the bcmap files are actually requested from: *my-application/assets/cmaps/Adobe-CNS1-UCS2.bcmap*

I don't understand that behaviour since the pdf.worker.min.js is correctly requested from *my-application/**en**/assets/*.

My **angular.json** assets setting looks like this:

```
"assets": [
   "src/favicon.ico",
   "src/assets",
   {
     "glob": "**/*",
     "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
     "output": "/assets/"
   }
]
```

Any tips what I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Author of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer here. Like you, I'm a bit confused. I your bug still persists, drop me an email at webmaster1 at beyondjava.de.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've found a bug. Either you update to version 5.0.1 (which fixes the bug). Or you use the default options for a workaround:

```
import { pdfDefaultOptions } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';
pdfDefaultOptions.cMapUrl = () => './' + pdfDefaultOptions.assetsFolder + '/cmaps/';
```